# How to take screenshots on Raspberry Pi effectively?

Tags: c++, c, linux, raspberry-pi, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the screen in my C++ code. The code is executed in the terminal.
I only have few milliseconds to capture the screen so I would like to use a code that is possibly really fast.
So far I have tried:

> System("import -window root screenshot.jpg");

but It fails stating that it doesn't recognize import.

I have also tried:

> System("sudo scrot");

which fails as well with this error: "Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?"

Any ideas on how to take a screenshot of screen really fast?

Comment: If your program is just producing text, you would probably find it useful to just send the output to a file with a command like `./myprog > log.txt` (redirects only, output not visible in terminal) or `./myprog | tee log.txt` (copies output to file, output also visible in terminal).

Comment: I would like to get a picture of everything that is shown on the screen not just the text. I would like to replicate the same effect that would happen on windows when you press "prt scr".

Comment: To get the `import` command, install the ImageMagick package.